# Moving WordPress From Subdirectory to Root

Tags: wordpress

I'm moving my WordPress site from a subdirectory of my site to the root. What do I have to change in order for the site to be functional at that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing more ...just change the site url and home url in wp_option table in database and reset permalinks in settings.

Comment: So this link is not necessary? - http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: So I've just moved the files and I renamed the URL in wp_option, but on the permalinks page I still have the old URL displayed (not to mention `g: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect` is occurring on this page as well).

Comment: Go to wordpress admin setting and then click on custom links radio and then select the preferred url style back so wordpress can regenarte the .htaccess ....

Comment: Yes, the URL was still set as the old one in the admin panel. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following are the steps you have to follow to move the subdirectory to the root.

1.move all the subdirectory files and folders to the root
2.take the back of your sql file.
3.Replace all the previous url with the new url in the sql(like http://expmle.com/sub to http://example.com)
4.import the replaced sql to the database.

Comment: Because of how new the site is, I know there are no references in the content of the DB to the current URL (and all old URL references have a redirect handling them) so I only had to move the files and change the permalinks. Thanks though!

Comment: You need to move the files and folders first..then you have to replace all the oldurl using the **replace all** option in the editor.and import the sql file in the database and type the new url to the address bar..it will work perfectly